# Generating token for connecting to azure sql takes too long

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I am trying to fetch token using GetAccessTokenAsync in C#, the code works fine and I am able to connect but the issue is it's taking too long to generate token(around 30 sec). Does anyone else facing similar issue?

```
var conn = (SqlConnection)this.Database.GetDbConnection();
conn.AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider()
                      .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/")
                      .Result;
```

Comment: Can you try using await on the call instead of using .Result?

Comment: I am using this in my constructor, so can't use async calls

Answer (score 0):

Can you please disable telemetry and try? Details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration?view=azure-cli-latest#cli-configuration-values-and-environment-variables). I believe it is the collect_telemetry option.

Comment: It's not set. Moreover, it takes same amount of time locally as well.